# Re-projecting an orthographic image to a equirectangular projection has some sort of problem. The poles are getting truncated. missing parameter?

Tags: interpolation, gdalwarp, parameters, syntax

[image]

Re-projecting an orthographic image to a equirectangular projection has some sort of problem.
The poles are getting truncated. is there a parameter I am missing?
Is there a difference between "eqc" "longlat" "plate-carree" ?
Is this a fundamental defect in gdal tools?

```
gdal_translate 
-of Gtiff 
-a_ullr -1666666 1666666 1666666 -1666666  
-a_srs 
    "+proj=ortho  
    +ellps=WGS84 
    +datum=WGS84 
    +lat_0=85 
    +lon_0=45"  
kat.png 
QQQQ-kat-ortho.tif 



gdalwarp 
-t_srs 
    "+proj=longlat 
    +datum=WGS84 
    +ellps=WGS84 
    +units=m"   
QQQQ-kat-ortho.tif
QQQQ-kat-latlon.tif 

gdal_merge.py  
-o QQQQ-kat-eq-merged.tif     
NE1_50M_SR_W_tenth.tif 
QQQQ-kat-latlon.tif

convert QQQQ-kat-eq-merged.tif QQQQ-kat-eq-merged.png

convert QQQQ-kat-latlon.tif QQQQ-kat-latlon.png
```

Comment: It looks like the flat image is sliced through the spherical image.

Comment: thank you Cary. So... you think it might be a "Force Interpolation" error ?

Comment: I'm feeling the issue is the target units in the gdalwarp should be decimal degrees, not meters.

Comment: thank you Jason. can you remind me please, what does that srs string look like with dec degs?
 -t_srs "+proj=eqc +datum=WGS84  +units=m"  +units=dd ???

Comment: Please post a before and after image that clearly shows your issue. And please stop double posting here and on stack overflow.

Comment: Polar areas in plate carree and similar projections are computationally difficult for many programs. The North Pole that is a point should be stretched into a line that fills the whole upper line from 180W to 180E. It is possible that some algorithm that GDAL is using is clipping the data above some latitude for avoiding division by zero errors or something like that. I do not know your use case but if you need to show your cat at the North Pole maybe you could select some polar projection like North Pole LAEA https://geoportal.arctic-sdi.org/.

Comment: Can you move the image to the equator to see if the problem persists?  Or post the image?  I know this is probably part of a bigger project but with a bit of code you could project both images to a sphere and then mask the "earth" one so that there is no way it will overlay the cat. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLb3g3wCEys

Comment: Thank you Cary. The problem only exists when the orthographic image is reprojected near the poles. if any part of the cat-map excedes 80deg's N or S, it gets truncated. I believe gdawarp has a built in limit when eqc is the output of 80 deg's. but there MUST be an over-ride, otherwise it would be forever impossible to create a full equirectangular map projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reprojecting an orthographic (ortho) or perspective (nsper) image to  equirectangular (eqc) when the map includes polar latitudes,

REQUIRES the target extents argument: "-te -180 -90 +180 +90"

or some other set of -te corners that EXPLICITLY extends all the way up to +/-90 Latitudes, else the default xmax is set to Latitude 85. Perhaps gdal REALLY expects Mercator and snips off poles. ?? This does not appear in the documentation anywhere.

example:

`gdalwarp -te -180 -90 +180 +90 -t_srs "+proj=eqc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m" source_ORTHO.tif target_EQC.tif`